# JAVA - unsimplify this lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I am not very experienced in JAVA. An associate at work was helping me with my assignment (for school) and he used a lambda expression. I understand that it is a shortcut... but I would like to understand what the original expression would be.

```
Collections.sort(salespeopleList, (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getUserID().compareTo(obj2.getUserID()));
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ quick google search and you can find things like [Lambda Expressions Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: this is good video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OpAgZvYXLQ

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions are not shortcuts, they are part of functional programming. 
It is similar to lambda expression in c#. 
(obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getUserID().compareTo(obj2.getUserID())

here obj1 and obj2 are inputs and the part on the right side of the arrow is the actual function(anonymous function if you want) and it does exactly what the methods signify.

Comment: I am asking because when I try Collections.reverseOrder i get many errors

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact name of the object class you are comparing, but assuming the class is "SalesPerson", it would look like this.

```
Collections.sort(salespeopleList, new Comparator<SalesPerson>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SalesPerson obj1, SalesPerson obj2) {
        return obj1.getUserID().compareTo(obj2.getUserID());
    }
});
```

In reference to the comment you just left while I was writing this

> "I am asking because when I try Collections.reverseOrder i get many errors"

If you do not have equals, hash, and compare set up in your object class, neither of the compares will work. You will need something like this in your object class

Answer (score 0):

The original implementation would require the use of an comparator, with a method that actually implements the lambda function.

For Example, making it more explicit by the use of the existing Comparator interface (to be more didactic):

```
public interface Comparator {
    int compare(T o1, T o2);
}

public class ObjsComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(SomeClass obj1, SomeClass obj2) {
        // This is your lambda implementation
        return obj1.getUserID().compareTo(obj2.getUserID());
    }
}

ObjsComparator mycomparator = new ObjsComparator();
Collections.sort(salespeopleList, mycomparator );
```

A less verbose approach would be:

```
Collections.sort(salespeopleList, new Comparator<SomeClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SomeClass obj1, SomeClass obj2) {
        // This is your lambda implementation
        return obj1.getUserID().compareTo(obj2.getUserID());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package testproject;
public class TestProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Compare compares = (a,b)->a.equals(b);
        Object test = new Object();
        System.out.println(new TestProject().compareTo(test, test, compares));
        System.out.println(new TestProject().compareTo(test, new Object(), compares));
    }

    interface Compare{
        boolean operation(Object a, Object b);
    }

    boolean compareTo(Object a, Object b, Compare localoperation)
    {
        return localoperation.operation(a, b);
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question, but if you are looking to have a better understanding of lambda expressions and how they work this article might be of better help.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_lambda_expressions.htm